# Get google forms to sync with spreadsheet on a schedule/interval rather than at every submission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

Potentially simple question, but I haven't been able to find an option in the basic Google Forms setup for this. I have a Google Form that will take in a high volume of submissions. The sheet it sends them to feeds them into a pivot table, among a few other relatively time-intensive operations. As a result, it takes about 20 seconds for everything to run and update every time there's a submission.

I think that these operations are essentially O(1) with the number of submissions coming in at a time because they mostly hinge on the pivot table updating, so it would be easier if I could just have the submissions sync every ten minutes or so and then have it run its ~20 seconds of operations, rather than with every submission.

Is anyone aware of a way to have Forms sync with a sheet on an interval rather than with each submission? (Maybe Google Scripts is helpful here?)

Comment: Is this causing issues with submissions?  If yes, use IMPORTRANGE()  in a second spreadsheet to import the submitted data and have your formulas, scripts, other work off that data.

Comment: It's not causing any issues with submissions (at least not yet), but especially because a lot of the submissions come in groups, it just causes the sheet to be constantly updating/recalculating the pivot table and cells dependent on the pivot table. It would serve its purpose just as well if it stayed updated every 10, 15 minutes or even every hour, but would spend less time updating.

Comment: I guess if there's no easy solution to getting it to update in intervals, there could be a workaround with IMPORTRANGE() though. Something like having it only import rows that are time-stamped up to yesterday. That's a helpful idea.

Comment: That functionality would require custom code.  IMPORTRANGE() will do a near real time import of the data.  It sounds as if you are constantly in the file as I would suspect it to not be a problem if the file is closed.  The other option would be a second file with an Import script to manually copy recent data in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some misunderstanding regarding the way that Google Forms and Google Sheets work together.

Looks that OP is using the built-in send form responses to a Google spreadsheet. This features works in only one direction, from the Google Form to the Google spreadsheet.

If the problem is that the Pivot Table or other calculations takes too long, one alternative is to use two different spreadsheets, one to receive the form responses and another to hold the formulas and the Pivot Table. You could use IMPORTRANGE to import the form responses which automatically refresh every 30 minutes (source  [Set a spreadsheet’s location and calculation settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en)).

Another alternative is to use a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).